# the meaning of ももたらず

Tags: words

My best translation of the following sentence is

関心{かんしん}ももたらずに放｛ほう｝っておきました。
Without sufficient interest, it's been neglected.

My guess is that たらず can be written as 足らず (insufficient), but I'm not sure what the も in も足らず should be. I can't find ももたらず in my usual dictionaries. The closest I've come is from this site, but I didn't fully understand the explanation in Japanese:

http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%82%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A

> 百に足りない数であるところから「八十{やそ}」「五十{いそ}」に、また「や」や「い」の音から「山田」「筏{いかだ}」などにかかる。
>
> 出典万葉集　三八一一
>
> 「ももたらず八十{やそ}の衢{ちまた}に」
>
> [訳] たくさんの道が通じた交差点に。
>
> 出典万葉集　三二七六
>
> 「ももたらず山田の道を」
>
> [訳] 山田の道を。

Comment: My best guess is that it's a typo of ももたずに, the second is ももたらさずに.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You wrongly understand the original Japanese sentence.

wrong: "関心"+"ももたらず"+"に"

wrong: "関心百足らず"　？？？

correct: "関心"+"も"+"もたずに（持たずに）" menas "without interest"

< The original phrase is "ももたらず"

"も（強調の「も」）"+"もたらず"

"もたらず" could be typo.

It should be "もたず".　＞

"も" of "関心ももたずに" is "強調の「も」."

つまり、"関心さえ持たずに"or"全く気にすることもなく"+"放っておきました"

"強調の「も」"examples: 「馬鹿でもわかる」「一言もしゃべらなかった」

"even the ignorant can understand", "kept absolutely quiet"

I've never heard "ももたらず（百足らず）"　for my 61 years life as a Japanese native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, the 「もも」in 「ももたらず」 means "One hundred" and the 「たらず」means 「足{た}りない」. 「百{ひゃく}」can be read as 「百{もも}」.

「八十{やそ}」or "Eighty" in English is less than 「百{もも}」"One hundred" hence the 「足{た}らず」in this saying.

EDIT: I should also state that this obviously just the literal translation of the words, not what the meaning of the whole saying is.

EDIT 2: I am not looking at the original statement, but this [「ももたらず八十の衢に」](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%82%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A)